# Peer to Peer Chat Security Options?

Tags: java, security, sockets

Ok, so for fun I am coding a messenger program in Java. Fun right? :)

I wanted to create a messenger that worked between two PC's tha didn't have to consult anyone else and you just input the IP you wish to chat with. Later I would implement a user name system where you contact the server to find out their IP.

I got the AES and RSA working perfecly and then I realized that a man in the middle attack is possible when you do the public private key exchange. This kinda makes me angry...

Is there any solution to a man in the middle attack other than using a CA or having a server exchange user names and/or public private key info?

Is there any programs already made like this that I can look to?

Thanks guys!

**Please note: Goal is to have secure peer to peer communication without a server. Also no vulnerabilities like man in the middle.**

Comment: Why can't you just use self signed certificates for https?

Comment: I could and wouldn't be a problem... but how would this help me?

Comment: Oh I see, b/c then you would have to include the cert with the program, allowing somebody to download the cert.

Comment: Yup, everything I think of keeps getting beaten down by man in the middle or is a server/CA which I don't want. Thanks for trying though

Comment: You could always use something heavier like SOAP. This would wrap the messages in a envelope with a mutual password agreed upon by the two people chatting when they add each other as friends? And use that password to hash it or something like that.

Comment: I will have to think about this more... that is for sure. That may be what I have to do... but don't want the clients to have to do that because if the blackhat can get the pass then were back at square one... and if I ever learned anything... you can't trust the end user to do it right LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are asking for too much. Public keys are secure if you use them correctly. If you do a "public private key exchange" that sounds insecure. Private keys never leave the host they are generated at.

Public keys are public and just bytes. It's a pair of numbers!! No other information. So here you **need** to choose:

1. Have a trusted **third party** with a shared server that associates public keys with identities. That's called CA :)
2. Exchange public keys in other secure ways. Examples: post on one's Facebook profile (browse it with HTTPS!), meet the other person, etc.

You might want to learn how PGP and Web Of Trust work. With WOT you can make a pretty good secure P2P chat in a social network fashion. Basically, you can still never join a P2P chat for the first time by typing an IP address, but after you do an initial work you can get a good result.

First, obtain someone's public key: **meet him/her**. By then, you can authenticate that party and he can authenticate you without possibility of attacks.

Phase 2 consists in building a trust chain. I'll explain that in social networking terms. You are party A, you met party B. You know each other. B knows C,D,E and later you meet F who is not known by B.

Ask B who are his friends (and get their public keys), you get to know C, D and E and you can contact them by then. Tell B you know F and he can contact them.

You might want to tell F about C, D and E that you know via A. This is very sensitive, because if the process is repeated indiscriminately a bad guy can easily enter the network. If you limit your trust to the "friends of friends" or up to a certain degree of indirect knowledge you can balance security.

I proposed you this way because you told you are doing this for fun and you are not in a business scenario!!

Comment: I know only public keys are sent. Phrased it wrong, my bad. However not completely knowledgeable with WOT. Always knew about it, but never really checked it out... as a result I forgot. Thanks, that is looking like a possible solution! +1

Comment: I hope you may understand the principles of WOT with social networking philosophy: when you know someone, you "trust" him. Do you trust who is trusted by whom you know? :)

Comment: Ya, I actually have a question. I thought you could put a password in with the private key... correct? Seems their is no option in the java.security.KeyPairGenerator. I know how to sign, but not how to put in the password for a PrivateKey when generated. Also, let me make sure I have the right idea. After you generate a private key and meet someone... verify it is their key with a fingerprint... you sign each others keys. How though, do you know someone else with the same name didn't sign it? THANKS MUCH! :) - To answer question: You trust that they are who they say they are.

Answer (score 2):

you have to choose: CA or shared secret. there is no other way. because otherwise how can you authenticate the other side? of course you can wrap it in ssl, pgp, password, OTR protocol or many others but this is just an abstraction layer. if you certainly don't want CA then you have to choose common secret. as @Shark said, OTR shows a good direction - you ask question, other side responses and you if the response is correct other side is authenticated

Comment: Answer does not prevent man in middle with asking a question, but very helpful... thanks. Did not see that in OTR, but +1

Comment: answer is for authentication. when side is authenticated you can easily establish secure communication. e.g. using diffie-hellman

Answer (score 1):

you need OTR. http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/

i'll help you test it once it's stable. been having the same idea for a while now.

Comment: I don't see what OTR would provide me other than "authentic messages"? This is the current problem I am trying to solve, everything else I have down. I put it on git and you can view it here: https://github.com/gemurdock/SecureMessenger - My email is on github

Comment: well there's a lib out. you can use the SMP (socialist millionare protocol) to exchange keys safely as far as i understood it. i could be wrong though...